# how to activate SysTreeView32 when folder-select dialog window is created?

Tags: winapi

When I create `SHBrowseForFolderW` dialog the default control is OK, what I need to do is make `SysTreeView32` active so a user can right on use arrow keys to adjust the desired folder. I tried to use this code : http://comp.newsgroups.archived.at/os.ms-windows.programmer.win32/200505/05053122835.html which wokrs ok in finding the HWND of the dialog but using `WM_NEXTDLGCTL` has no effect on the window.

Maybe I should send TAB keystrokes to the window, or I don't know any other opions ? Are there swiches in creating the browse dialog what control will be highlighted when the window create ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the thing is difference between PostMessage and SendMessage. I mistakenly used the later here. They are not the same!